# How to install a plugin in redmine 1.4.4 via SSH on redmine VM?

Tags: plugins, ssh, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have got access to redmine VM via SSH and have plugin files on my local machine. Now I need to install it in redmine.

Can anyone explain the steps to do it? I am using a windows 7 machine as SSH client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SFTP client such as [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) (Windows client that I uses) or [find any other](https://www.google.com/search?q=sftp%20client&rct=j).

SFTP is SSH File Transfer Protocol, i.e. you will have access to VM's file system via SSH connection, and Redmine plugins installation will be just files copying :)

Also, SFTP clients can launch simple commands as `touch` (`touch tmp/restart.txt` command needed to restart Ruby on Rails applications)

Answer (score 0):

Put the plugin directory in the `vendor/plugins` sub directory of your Redmine installation. Check the plugin installation instructions for any additional steps that might be necessary.

Redmine 1.4.4 is several years old, you should first make sure with a local test that the plugin actually works with that version. And you should *really* upgrade to a recent version of Redmine (current stable is 3.2) as there have been quite a few security issues in Rails and Redmine since 1.4.4 was released.